# Save popup.html info for next session

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I feel like this is simple, but I can't figure it out.

My app basically makes modification to the popup.html page by doing a document.getElementById which works perfectly.

```
[..]
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "inserting data here"
[..]
```

As expected, when clicking away from the popup.html, the page closes. When it opens back up, the modification is no longer there.

I've been looking at background pages https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/background?csw=1#example-permission to try and get that sorted out, but it doesn't feel like it would do what I'd need to.

Does anyone have any recommendations
?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to store the values when popup opens like this

```
localStorage.setItem('mydata', 'inserting data here')
```

and when popup loads you can fetch the value from it

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('mydata')
```

so your code would be something like this

```
if(localStorage.getItem('mydata')) {
   document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('mydata')
} else {
   localStorage.setItem('mydata', 'inserting data here')
}
```

if the popup has same domain as the main page it will work fine

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks so much. I guess I would just need to get it to have a listener to load it up as soon as the pop-up is open. I'll have to research that.

Comment: you can just use window.onload = function () { // include localStorage set get here } or if your are using jquery you can use $(function () {}); Please accept answer if it has cleared your doubts :)

Comment: It took me a while to get the chrome.storage.local.get working, but it seems it's up and running now! THanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chromes built-in storage APIs to accomplish this.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

// In your manifest

```
"permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
```

// Saving

```
function saveChanges() {
  // Get a value saved in a form.
  var theValue = textarea.value;
  // Check that there's some code there.
  if (!theValue) {
    message('Error: No value specified');
    return;
  }
  // Save it using the Chrome extension storage API.
  chrome.storage.local.set({'value': theValue}, function() {
    // Notify that we saved.
    message('Settings saved');
  });
}
```

// Retrieving

```
chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(data) {
   // act upon data.
});
```

Comment: You are not "unable to use the typical localStorage apis." They work just fine. The main advantage of `chrome.storage.local` over `localStorage` is that the former is accessible to content scripts.

Comment: Perhaps I'm thinking of Chrome Packaged Apps that don't allow you to use localStorage. My answer has been corrected nonetheless. Thanks